# Can I have a set and a hset with same name?

Tags: java, database, redis, jedis

what will be the output of the given code?
can Jedis hold two data sets of different types in the the DB but with the same name?
if not, at the printing line, what will j.get returns? Is j.set cast into j.hset?

i'm new to Redis databases

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Jedis j = new Jedis("slc09sro");
    try {
        j.set("alex1", "1");
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    try {
        j.set("alex1", "2");
    } 
    catch (Exception e){}
    try {
        j.hset("alex1", "3", "4");
    } 
    catch (Exception e){}
    System.out.println(j.get("alex1"));
    j.close;
}
```

Comment: "what will be the output of the given code?" Have you tried? You already have the code, so execute it and see the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example will fail while trying to use the `hset` method. Simple example with no Java necessary:

```
$ redis-cli 
127.0.0.1:6379> set alex1 1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set alex1 2
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> hset alex1 3 4
(error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
127.0.0.1:6379> get alex1
"2"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

This is because the key `alex1` holds a string value, not a hash. After the unsuccessful `HSET` call, the key remains unchanged from the last `SET` call, thus containing the string value `"2"`.

See the [Redis command reference](https://redis.io/commands):

- [SET](https://redis.io/commands/set)
- [HSET](https://redis.io/commands/hset)